# Как нажать на кнопку в расширении браузера с помощью javascript(tampermonkey)?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Допустим, у меня есть расширение letyshops, я хочу нажать на кнопку "войти" через tampermonkey, либо через браузерную консоль разработчика, я знаю как нажать на кнопку просто в браузере, но тот же способ для расширения не подходит, вот данные кнопки "войти" из расширения letyshops

`<div id="letyshops-header-entry" class="letyshops-header-entry"> <span>войти</span> </div>`

Comment: Почему не подходит?

Comment: Какие же вы ленивые [симулирование клика по объекту](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#javascript)